# Calculate the average in SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using SSRS 2016 application to pull data from SharePoint list.
My task is to calculate the average DaysUsed and the average Percentage from a column.

It is a Matrix report which has two columns:

- Sum(Fields!Days.Value)
- Sum(Fields!Percentage.Value)

The task is to show the average days and average percentage.
I have tried the `=Avg(Fields!Days.Value)` but this shows wrong result.

[image]

UPDATE

Yes, the matrix is grouped by the Month to show each relevant month. 
See the screenshot below what I have tested so far.

[image]

The DaysUsed is a calculated between 2 fields [FromDate] and [UntilDate] by summarising the total days minus the weekends. see below:

```
=(DateDiff(DateInterval.day,CDate(format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")), CDate(format(Fields!UntilDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")))+1)
- (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,CDate(format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")), CDate(format(Fields!UntilDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")))*2) 
- IIF(Weekday( CDate(format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")),1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday( CDate(format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")),1) = 7,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday( CDate(format(Fields!UntilDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")),1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday( CDate(format(Fields!UntilDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")),1) = 7,1,0)
```

Furthermore, the [DaysUsed] row then consists of IIF(value is null then show 0 otherwise show the total value of days used).

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Days.Value)), "0", Sum(Fields!Days.Value) )
```

Comment: shall your AvgDays not be 34/6=5.66 and 75/6=12.5 ???

Comment: @AnkUser that is correct :) I fail to make the SSRS say "use Sum(....) / Count(...) but I obviously not good at this :)

Comment: No worries I guess you got that now.  I will write down the answer would be great if you mark it. Shall be good to earn some points

Answer (score 0):

```
Sum(Fields!Days.Value)/CountRows()
```

Shall give you average days. Similarly goes for others as well.

Comment: I tried this already but it gives me 2 for average days. Also, if I only use `CountRows() then it shows me 14 instead 6 because there are 6 rows due to from January until June (current month).

Comment: what does  Count(Fields!Days.Value) returns? if it returns 6 then use that. Also are you grouping your data or hiding few Rows. If you do so then what does CountDistinct(Fields!Days.Value) returns. if it returns 6 then use that for division

Comment: yes the Matrix is grouped by the Month to show all days and percentage from beginning of the year until current month.  See my edited topic:

Comment: the `Count(Fields!Days,Value)` results in 14 for the first column which I am not sure how it gets there ....

Comment: ok and what about `CountDistinct(Fields!Days.Value)` what does it returns?

Comment: with the `CountDistrinct()` it results 4 in 1st column and 6 in 2nd column

Comment: ok got it, don't use `CountDistinct(Fields!Days.Value)´ 
rather use`CountDistinct(Fields!Months.Value)´
I am not sure how your month field is name, but use that it will return you 6 in both the columns. Let me know.

Comment: right :) I used the `=CountDistinct(Fields!Month.Value)` and it shows the right count result :)))) now, the only drawback is that any rows with a value of 0 is not counted. Which then results in the average being wrong because 34/3=11.33 and 34/6=5.66

Comment: Strange, it should give you 6. How are you getting your Month value. Do one thing edit your question and show me your original data without any grouping and so on. Then it will be clear what are you missng.

Comment: Well, it seems to be a normal behaviour, the count will only take values above 0 and exclude any NULL values... as per google search.  I have updated the topic/.

Comment: any update on this ... the `=CountDistinct()` ignores any NULL / 0 rows :(

Answer (score 0):

If you has a field called `Fields!Days.Value`, I guess your data in the screenshot is already grouped by month. This means the expression

```
=Avg(Fields!Days.Value)
```

gives you the average over all Days (sum of all days / count of all days).

If you want to use the grouped values (by mounth) you either can use the following expression when you are inside the scope (the monthly socpe; indicated by the brackets on the most left side on your tablix)

```
=Sum(Fields!Days.Value) / Count(Fields!Days.Value)
```

If you are not in the scope you have to tell the tablix that is should use your monthly grouping. For this you can use the following:

```
=Sum(Fields!Days.Value, "YourMonthGroupName") / Count(Fields!Days.Value, "YourMonthGroupName")
```

Comment: You are right, it is grouped by Month: the row is named as GroupByMonth and the column is named as GroupByPoolCar

Comment: also, I tried your last suggested syntax but somehow figures do not match .... see attached image in my initial topic.

Comment: any advise on why the CountDistinct ignores the NULL values ...?